# Как в дебаггере GoLand при запуске теста установить переменную окружения?

Tags: golang, юнит-тесты, отладка, jetbrains

При запуске теста в дебаггере мне необходимо перед этим установить переменную окружения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напрасно лазал там где окно вывода информации, настройки дебага в панели которая вверху, где дропдаун с запущенными кусками.

Answer (score 0):

Установите в самом тесте

```go
err := os.Envset("key", value)
```

По окончанию теста не забудьте переменную вернуть в исходное состояние.